# php and mysql with maths

Tags: php, mysql

Let me try to explain what I want to do the best I can.

1. Count mysql results.
2. Divide it by 10
3. Then show how many pages there are by numbers.

What I mean is let’s say my sql have 100 rows so you divide it by 10 and you get 10 so I need to show this

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

And if it is 102 rows it will show

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
```

This is to use with jQuery Masonry pagination.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
<?php

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM posts") or die (mysql_query());
$num = mysql_num_rows($sql);

$tot = $num / 10;

?>
```

Hope everyone understood what i need. thanks in advance

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained, are [officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp) and can be [dangerous in live code](http://bit.ly/4zUdtT). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Why do you want to use MySQL for this?

Comment: ya sorry about that im gonna use MySQLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
list($max) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select ceil(count(`id`)/10) from posts"));
echo implode(", ",range(1,$max));
```

Answer (score 3):

you can get to number of pages like this from mysql.

```
SELECT CEIL(count(*)/10) FROM posts
```

then just use a for loop in your php to make the pages

Comment: And use `mysql_result($sql,1);` to pull the first result into a variable

Comment: sorry for the dumb question but can you please tell me how to echo it out also